# How to turn regular list into option list

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec some_none list =
  match list with
  | [] -> list
  | hd::tl -> 
      if hd = 0 then 
        [None] @ some_none tl 
      else
        [Some hd] @ some_none tl;;
```

When I run this program it returns

```
Error: This expression has type int list but an expression was expected of type
     'a option list
   Type int is not compatible with type 'a option
```

How can I make it so that I am able to change a regular `a' list` to `a' option list`?

Answer (score 5):

These two lines

```
  match list with
  | [] -> list
```

imply that the list returned by `some_none` has the same type as its argument.
Changing that line to

```
  | [] -> []
```

solves the issue, since the left-hand and right-hand side are now unrelated.
A more subtle way (and not really useful here) is to use the `as` construct,

```ml
  | [] as x -> x
```

because `... as x` construct captures the type of the pattern rather than the type of the scrutinee (here list). However, this construction is mostly useful with polymorphic variants.

Also notice that your function `some_none` change neither the length of the list nor the order of the elements of the list. This means that it can be written as a map:

```
let some_none = List.map (fun elt -> ... )
```

Comment: When you say write it as a map do you mean just apply x to Some x and 0 to None how would you write fun elt?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to what octachron has already said, there's a few style and performance issues with your code too.

First, it's unnecessary to create a new list in order to concatenate it using `@` when `::` exists to prepend a single element to a list:

```
let rec some_none list  =
  match list with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl ->
      if hd = 0 then 
        None :: some_none tl
      else
        Some hd :: some_none tl
```

Second, you can match on literal patterns directly instead of using comparison in an if expression within the branch:

```
let rec some_none list  =
  match list with
    | [] -> []
    | 0::tl -> None :: some_none tl
    | hd::tl -> Some hd :: some_none tl
```

Third, you can use `function` to match directly on the last function argument:

```
let rec some_none = function
  | [] -> []
  | 0::tl -> None :: some_none tl
  | hd::tl -> Some hd :: some_none tl
```

And fourth, you can use `List.map` to transform elements individually:

```
let some_none =
  List.map (function 0 -> None | x -> Some x)
```

And now you have a function that is suddenly much easier to read and understand fully.

Comment: The last answer you gave is still giving an error that it should not be a function

Comment: That what should not be a function? It works fine for me.

Comment: There is probably an `open Base` somewhere. In this case, the `Base` variant of the `List.map` function requires a label: `List.map ~f:(function 0 -> None | x -> Some x)`.

Comment: In your "Third" step you silently change the `[] -> list` to `[] -> []`, which is the actual error that was asked about in the question. You should lead with that and that alone in your answer. The rest is just prettying it up.

Comment: I don't see any reason to repeat what others have already said, which is why I started by saying i was adding to that. I definitely should have fixed the error in the first two examples though. Thanks for pointing that out. The actual question asked is "How to turn regular list into option list", which is answered by each of my examples, in different forms to show how it could be progressively improved to reach better answers to the question asked.